# SQL - Generate intervals based on Range of Dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, date-range

I've a challenge, but I even don't know if it will be possible to solve the way I need.

I need to transform the information on the left table into the data of the right table.

[image]

Is it possible to archive this results **without** using procedures (T-SQL, PLSQL)(I can use intermediate tables to store transformations and so one, but I can't use procedures).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what the transformation is?

Comment: can you use redshift procedures? see. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

Comment: can you have a situation where there are >2 sequences for a cust/prod/rule?

Comment: @JonScott
If we have another entry for cust/prod/rule it will have a different Seq.
Let's say if we have an entry like : 
Cust | Prod | Rule 
X      |    Y   |    A 

It will have another a different Seq and different dates

Comment: as per first comment from gordon-linoff, its critical that you explain the transformation you are seeking more fully.

Comment: By transformations I mean intermediate calculations (ex: store data into aux tables).